# CodeIgniter Upload Errors Not Showing

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, error-handling, upload

I've been following the CodeIgniter File Upload tutorial [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) a few days ago.

At the point of completing the tutorial, the upload field worked fine showing errors for invalid file path, type and dimensions.

But now it just displays and error for invalid file path but not for file type or dimensions. When trying to upload an invalid file type or dimensions, the upload field just becomes blank with no error messages.

Here's my code:

**Upload Controller**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Upload extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper("form");
        $this->load->helper("url");
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view("templates/index");
    }

    public function upload_form()
    {
        $this->load->library("upload_helper");
        $config = $this->upload_helper->upload_config("./static_repo/uploads/", "gif|jpg|png", 100, 1024, 768);
        $this->load->library("upload", $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload("userfile"))
        {
            $data = array(
                "error" => $this->upload->display_errors()
            );

            $this->load->view("upload/upload_form_page", $data);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array(
                "upload_data" => $this->upload->data()
            );

            $this->load->view("upload/upload_success_page", $data);
        }
    }
} //end class Upload
```

**HTML Form**

```
<?= $error ?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20">
    <br/><br/>
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

Comment: where is the action for the form??

Comment: Make `$config` similar to docs' example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it.

Had to modify the post_max_size php.ini on my local wamp server.